# looking for how to transfer file to 200 terminals (windows-mobile)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i have 200 terminals (Windows-mobile) that connect to the server Through WIFI

how i can transfer any file to all of them ?

is there any tool or can i get any C# sample code for this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should write some sw on the mobiles to sink the file instead of pushing on them. So each user can ask the server for transfer the file. If the file you need to transfer is a deploy of an application, you can even consider some strategy of auto upgrade as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446487.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a log-on script assuming you have Active Directory and a friendly system administrator.

http://www.rlmueller.net/LogonScriptFAQ.htm

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a non-free tool called [System Center Configuration Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager.aspx) that will do what you want. You need to install the client app on the phones first, then they poll the server for updates.

This is likely to be massive overkill for what you want but it's hard to be sure from the question.